# Mover archivo de local a servidor por ssh o sftp

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, spool

Uso el spool para capturar el resultado de una consulta simple y pasarlo a un TXT que coloco en mi máquina local en C:\TXT. Pero necesito depositar ese archivo en un directorio remoto usando ssh. ¿Cómo podría hacerse?

Estuve investigando para ver si desde el spool podría llegarle así por ejemplo:

```
SET PAGESIZE 1000 LINESIZE 200 ECHO OFF TRIMS ON FEEDBACK OFF HEA OFF
SPOOL //100.10.10.99/mnt/mi_directorio/archivo.txt
@consulta.sql;
SPOOL OFF
```

Sin embargo esto no es soportado por SqlPlus.

Vi algo de UTP_FILE, pero no es simple. He pensado en tener el local y mover desde Linux via consola con un batch.

Comment: Como comentas, una buena solución podría ser utilizar una shell que te ayude con ambas tareas: la ejecución del sql y el posterior envío del archivo de salida, vía SFTP a tu máquina de destino.

Comment: Gracias a todos los colaboradores,  voy a intentarlo como describo y comento para aportar valor a esta entrada.

Comment: Como comentario de apoyo, el usuario que ejecute la shell debe tener definida la variable ORACLE_HOME, para poder ejecutar el script del spool sin problemas. Si tienes algo de código, sería bueno que lo publicaras también como edición de tu pregunta.